# Can't solve "No module named 'numpy'" after hours of digging

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I know this is a problem that's been asked here before, but I have tried all the solutions I found and not solved it. It's possible I'm not understanding the solutions, but I have tried my best.

I am teaching myself Python and it is slow going, so I don't understand a lot yet. I'm using VSCode as an IDE, Python version 3.10, and Windows 10. I only have the Python extension installed for VSCode. My project files are on a flash drive, D. I replaced a couple folder names with [Default Names] in the text below.

I keep trying to debug/run some code in VSCode and the very first line
`import numpy as np`
gives me the error
`Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError - No module named 'numpy'.`

But I know that's not true:

```
`PS D:\0-Career\Programming\PythonCoding\[ProjectFolder]> py -m pip install numpy   
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\[UserID]\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.23.1)`
```

I tried the solution of going to

```
environment variables > system variables > "Path" > edit > new >
c:\users\[UserID]\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\
```

as well as
`C:\Users\[UserID]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\`
and
`C:\Users\[UserID]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\`
and I also tried adding a user variable called Python. Nothing appears to have changed as a result of these additions.

Some history if it's helpful:
I first started by installing Python using the Microsoft Store. I used IDLE for a bit, and I used my command line to install pip and numpy. They worked for a little while. I later installed Visual Studio Code IDE. I ultimately have uninstalled the Microsoft Store version and installed the application from the Python site for Windows instead. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled it several times trying to fix my issues, and same for numpy. I also searched my C drive for "python" and burned everything from the past couple days and reinstalled and repaired it out of desperation. No luck.

I have tried to the best of my ability to uninstall everything and reinstall everything to start fresh, because numpy worked ever so briefly early on in IDLE, I think until I had installed the web download version of Python. I don't really understand environment variables, so I'm not sure what I'm doing or if I'm doing that wrong, or what needs to be restarted when I try something new, so it's possible I missed something.

Answers a 10 year old could understand would be appreciated! Or terminology I can easily research for an explanation of how to do it.

Comment: In VS Code, open a terminal and run the following commands to verify where it is running Python from and which version.  1) `python` (starts Python interpreter -- note the version it shows); 2) `import sys`; 3) `import os`; 4) `os.path.dirname(sys.executable`.   

If this shows the path to a different install of Python than the one you think you are using, that is likely your problem.  Are you in a virtual environment?

Comment: Can you update your question with what command you are using to run your script (which causes the import error), or if you are using VS Code to run it? I ask because, I see you are running `py -m pip install numpy` to install Numpy and I'm curious if you're running your script as `py MYFILE.py` (same `py`?), because, if you are installing Numpy in a *different* Python than the one you are running your script with, that would explain why the latter cannot find Numpy. I've never seen Python abbreviated as `py` so I want to make sure you're using `py` for both steps.

Comment: @ekrall
(1) PS C:\Users\[UserID]> py
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32; (2) this didn't return anything; (3) this didn't return anything; (4) >>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
'C:\\Users\\[UserID]\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'. I'm not sure about the virtual environment. I think I might be, because a tutorial had me create a .venv, but my problems started before that. I tried creating a new workspace, but now I can't figure out how to get the python debugger working; it thinks my files are plaintext.

Comment: @AhmedFasih I am currently running script in VSCode, and "python" doesn't seem to be recognized. My command prompt accepts both py and python. I have to sleep now but in the morning I may try to attach some screenshots of exactly what I do and see.

Comment: In your comment you say you've created a venv. Could it be you've installed numpy on system python and are running in the venv (without numpy) or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> open Command Palette
2. choose **Python:Select Interpreter**
3. Choose the right interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Also Check 64 bit or 32 bit

Download the latest version

and open the location where you downloaded the NumPy module now press the 'SHIFT' key and press right-click on the mouse then a menu will open where you find open PowerShell. open it now PowerShell window opens in the folder now type pip install and the file name and press the TAB button and click enter. then the NumPy module will be installed. [image: SEE THIS IMAGE]

Have Fun

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the variable PYTHONPATH to your system variables and add the following paths to this variable.

C:\PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON_INSTALL

C:\PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON_INSTALL\DLLs

C:\PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON_INSTALL\Lib

C:\PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON_INSTALL\Scripts

It should look something like this.
[Screenshot of Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYbal.png)

After you added the variable restart your VS Code and it should work.
I hope this helps.